# yeoman this.npmInstall is not a function

Tags: npm, yeoman

In the lastest yeoman, `this.npmInstall()` is deprecated, which function can replace this? such as I want to install vue

```js
this.npmInstall(['vue'], { 'save-dev': false });
this.npmInstall(['webpack', "vue-loader"], { 'save-dev': false });
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [release notes for v5.0.0](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/releases/tag/v5.0.0), this functionality was "replaced by package.json manipulation". Use these global methods instead:

- `addDependencies({ dependency: 'version' });`
- `addDevDependencies({ dependency: 'version' });`

Unfortunately, the documentation for [managing dependencies](https://yeoman.io/authoring/dependencies.html) is out-of-date, though [there is a *help-needed* issue for it](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/1294).

Answer (score 0):

I believe `spawnCommandSync` still works:

```
this.spawnCommandSync('npm', ['i', 'vue', 'vue-loader', 'webpack']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const packageJson = {}
this.fs.extendJSON(this.destinationPath('package.json'), packageJson)
this.spawnCommand('npm', ['i', 'vue', 'vue-loader', 'webpack'])
```

If you use like this, `spawnCommand` will work well.